# Some imports not found in added CocoaPods project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I am new to iOS dev, with zero knowledge of Xcode/objc/CocoaPods. While studying Swift I wanted to try integrating an existing Obj-c project using CocoaPods. The project I am including is called CCHMapClusterController. I am getting *.h header "file not found" when building. What is causing this?

Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.2'
use_frameworks!

target 'TennisBuddy' do
pod "CCHMapClusterController"
end

target 'TennisBuddyTests' do
end
```

I created a "bridge" header file. Compiler is complaining that some of headers are not found (some are). 
[image]

Build settings:
[image]

Comment: This happens to me too. Any news about it?

Comment: @Gorka no, unfortunately I ended up manually moving files into my project. Too bad, I really wanted to do it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "YTKKeyValueStore.h"
#import "../Pods/Headers/Private/FMDB/FMDB.h"
```

Look at the second '#import', maybe you should include the full path.
This works for me.